# Dealing with a large amount of text data in JavaScript/VS code

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am working on a react native app that has a lot of text data and the plan is to make it work offline so its all going to be compiled in the app. Its a resource app so there are a few categories but basically it is 400 articles in 3 or 4 categories each (1200-1600 total), or at least for the higher volume ones. Currently about 30% through the first one and it is approaching 18,000 lines in an object. Would it be faster and more efficient to have each article in a json and bring it in by name compared to one object? I don't think look up would be slow in the object because there are only 400 or so ids to look up but I am running into an issue with vscode getting really slow. The text is made outside the file and I copy it in but copying the ids for reference throughout the app is getting slow and it made me reconsider how I am storing the data. I am not seeing any performance issues on the app so far as it is loaded into a flatlist but I am curious if there is a better way to handle it in code.

I looked around online and saw more info on rendering it, which is not an issue and I think this is a bit more of a VSCode issue.

Comment: Json file is minified?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your articles are primarily intended for `reading`, consider organizing them efficiently. You can create a folder structure that `categorizes` `articles` into separate folders. In React Native, you can then import articles using a `clear folder structure` like this:

```js
import article1 from '../articles/category1/article1.json';
```

This approach `simplifies` article management and enhances overall organization.

**Making dynamic:** Assuming you have the same project structure

```js
project/
├─ src/
│   ├─ articles/
│   │   ├─ category1/
│   │   │   ├─ article1.json
│   │   │   ├─ article2.json
│   │   │   └─ ...
│   │   ├─ category2/
│   │   │   ├─ article1.json
│   │   │   ├─ article2.json
│   │   │   └─ ...
│   │   ├─ category3/
│   │   │   ├─ article1.json
│   │   │   ├─ article2.json
│   │   │   └─ ...
```

You can structure your code as follows for **dynamical import** `article`:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

async function loadArticle(category, articleName) {
  try {
    const articleModule = require(`../articles/${category}/${articleName}.json`);
    return articleModule.default; // Assuming articles are exported as default
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error loading article: ${error}`);
    return null;
  }
}

const YourComponent = () => {
  const category = 'category1';
  const articleName = 'article1';

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchArticle() {
      const article = await loadArticle(category, articleName);
      if (article) {
        console.log(article);
      } else {
        console.log('Article not found or error loading.');
      }
    }
    fetchArticle();
  }, [category, articleName]);

  return (
    // Your component JSX here
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think that makes more sense from a structure standpoint compared to an unwieldy object file. I just was not sure if there would be a performance issue as right now the card info (title, image location and subtitles) are in the object but I am just realizing I could have an object with just those things and it would bring that object down to about 2000-3000 lines of code which would be easier to handle.

Comment: Can you mark answer answer as accepted! thanks

Comment: Done. It's been working great and no hard numbers but it definitely feels more responsive this way. Thanks again!